# Javascript: Custom date/time format with Moment js returns "Invalid date"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a time value `10:30:00` and I want to convert it to `10:30 AM` using momentjs, however I am getting an "Invalid date".

My code currently looks like this:

```
var time = '10:30:00';

var formattedTime = moment(time).format("hh:mm A");

console.log(formattedTime); // Invalid date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the format of your input time string of `'10:30:00'` not matching [any of the supported string formats](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) that are directly compatible with `moment()`.

You can however [specify a custom format pattern](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to achieve what your require, by passing the custom pattern as a second argument to `moment()` (which in your case would be the pattern `'hh:mm:ss'`):

```
moment('10:30:00', 'hh:mm:ss')
```

Consider revising your code as shown below:

```js
var time = '10:30:00';
var formattedTime = moment(time, 'hh:mm:ss') /* <-- specify a custom pattern */
.format("hh:mm A");

console.log(formattedTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```